# What is the BOOT.conf file used for?

Tags: rhel, grub2, system-installation, iso

I am trying to create an custom install ISO for RHEL 8.

On the installation ISO, there are 2 files in the `EFI/BOOT/` directory: `BOOT.conf` and `grub.cfg`. The `diff` command doesn't show any difference between the two. I couldn't find any place that discusses `BOOT.conf`.

What is it used for in the installation process? And, do I have to make the same changes I made to `grub.cfg` to the `BOOT.conf`?

Comment: I'm facing the same doubt. In the `isolinux` folder happens something similar, there are `isolinux.cfg` and `grub.conf` files. Have you already found out the answer to this question?

Comment: @acampana I found an answer to this question.  I just changed them both and it worked.  I didn't try only changing one.

Comment: @acampana I never noticed the isolinux.cfg/grub.conf issue.  I just changed the isolinux.cfg.  However, I found a partial answer: isolinux/isolinux.cfg & EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg control the boot menu on BIOS & UEFI systems respectively.  More ino can be found at: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/anaconda_customization_guide/sect-boot-menu-customization  Still haven't found out what BOOT.conf is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On RHEL 9 installation media, such duplication no longer exists: there is no `EFI/BOOT/BOOT.conf` any more, only `EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`.

When running `grep -i BOOT.conf EFI/BOOT/*.efi`, there are no hits, but when running `grep -i grub.cfg EFI/BOOT/*.efi`, a match is found in both `grubx64.efi` and `grubia32.efi`. It suggests that the GRUB EFI binaries look for `grub.cfg`, not for `BOOT.conf`.

Also, those GRUB `*.efi` binaries are the only things that would have a reason to read the `grub.cfg` file which defines a boot menu that is only good for booting from a local installation media, as the kernel boot option `inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=RHEL-8-8-0-BaseOS-x86_64` tells the installer code in initramfs to look for local disk/disc with a particular volume label.

Based on all of the above, my theory is that the `BOOT.conf` is simply a result of a minor bug in a script used to create the installation images.

---

The case of the `isolinux` directory seems different, as the `isolinux.cfg` and `grub.conf` files there have entirely different contents.

The ISOLINUX bootloader has its own configuration syntax, and it would not understand a configuration file meant for GRUB.

Also, the `isolinux/grub.conf` file is much shorter than `EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`. Its entire contents are:

```
#debug --graphics
default=1
splashimage=@SPLASHPATH@
timeout 60
hiddenmenu
title Install Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8
        findiso
        kernel @KERNELPATH@ @ROOT@ quiet
        initrd @INITRDPATH@
title Test this media & install Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8
        findiso
        kernel @KERNELPATH@ @ROOT@ rd.live.check quiet
        initrd @INITRDPATH@
```

Note the variables `@SPLASHPATH@`, `@KERNELPATH@`, `@ROOT@` and `@INITRDPATH@`: this looks like a *template for creating a very minimalist GRUB configuration file* for booting off a ISO9660-based installation media. It does **not** seem like a valid GRUB configuration file as-is.

Perhaps RedHat was testing the feasibility of using GRUB as the bootloader for BIOS-based booting off the installation media too, but then decided against it and kept using ISOLINUX just like in the previous major releases? And when the process was changed, a template file intended for creating a GRUB configuration for that purpose was accidentally included in the `isolinux` directory?

It would be technically a bug, but since the file is small and apparently completely ineffective and harmless in its current location, the priority for fixing it would be very low.